# Deliver a message after returning the function result

Tags: r

Consider the following function `foo`

```
foo <- function(x) {
    print(x)
    message("test message")
}
```

I'd like to deliver the message **after** the result of the function so that if the result is long I don't have to scroll up to see if there was an important message (or change my `max.print` option).  The issue is when I want to assign the result without printing the actual result.

Is there a way to print the result of the function, followed by the message, but also so that when I assign the result nothing at all is printed? Ideally, I'd like to avoid the use of `print` altogether.

The desired result without assignment is

```
> foo(5)                            
# [1] 5
# test message
```

The desired result with assignment is

```
> bar <- suppressMessages(foo(5))
> bar
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Normally assignments don't print the result. Do you want to change that behavior as well? Do you intend to keep the `print()` in `foo()`?

Comment: @MrFlick I'd rather not use `print` at all.

Comment: But you still want to see the result after assignment as in your examples? Because that also involves changing the `<-` operator.

Comment: I do not want so see any result when assigning, but I want the message printed after the function result when not assigning

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a class for your `foo` function, e.g. `bar`, and then creating a print method for this new class.

For example:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("bar", class(x))
  x
}


print.bar <- function(x, message=TRUE, ...){
  class(x) <- setdiff("bar", class(x))
  NextMethod(x)
  if(message)   message("test message")

}
```

Now try it:

```
foo(5)
[1] 5
test message
```

With assignment:

```
x <- foo(5)
x
[1] 5
test message
```

Some other ways of interacting with the `print` method:

```
print(x, message=FALSE)
[1] 5

suppressMessages(print(x))
[1] 5
```