# print simple message (not warning) at end of output

Tags: r

Is it possible to print a diagnostic (simple) message at the end of an output, yet still returning a value? In below example, all attempts of returning a data frame and showing the message at the end do not work.

I get the desired effect using `warning()` - funnily only in my R session but not when using `reprex` - so is this maybe a question of option settings?

```r
sort_message1 <- function() {
  message("that comes too early")
  data.frame(a = 1)
}
sort_message2 <- function() {
  data.frame(a = 1)
  message("should return the data frame too")
}
sort_message3 <- function() {
  print(data.frame(a = 1))
  message("prints the data frame, but does not return it")
}
sort_message4 <- function() {
  return(data.frame(a = 1))
  message("does obviously not print message")
}
sort_message1()
#> that comes too early
#>   a
#> 1 1
sort_message2()
#> should return the data frame too
sort_message3()
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> prints the data frame, but does not return it
sort_message4()
#>   a
#> 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `message` should come first not last. `return` will stop execution

Comment: @NelsonGon I am aware that return will stop execution. why should messages come first?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122340/how-do-i-display-a-message-to-user-at-the-end-of-a-functions-return-output) I think `message` is a form of print and therefore requires a new print method as done in this link.

Comment: You want to use `on.exit(message(...))` before your return statement.

Comment: @NelsonGon I guess this makes my question a duplicate then :) thanks for showing

Comment: If you want to return muliple objects of different types, you can store them as a list and then return the list.  e.g. `msg <- "test msg"; df <- mtcars ; mylist <- list(msg, df) ; return(mylist)`

Comment: @SteveM thanks for the suggestion! This would be a workaround, but not very desired, because in the end I want only one object returned.