# How can I get the order of plots correct in an rmd? [How can I control the print-time of messages?]

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

As the minimal reproducible example below shows, plot 2 appears too late.
How can I fix this?

It seems, the `message` screws everthing up. Most likely related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499276/deliver-a-message-after-returning-the-function-result) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937741/print-simple-message-not-warning-at-end-of-output?noredirect=1&lq=1).

````
---
title: "Run all test-cases"
author: "STCH"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
    code_folding: hide
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.width = 10)
testfun <- function() {
    message("in testfun")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    plot(3, main = "testfun 3")
    return(0)
  }
```

# All test cases `decreasing.benefits = TRUE`

```{r}
for (i in 1){#c(1:7)) {
  cat("====================================================================\n")
  plot(1, main = "1")
  
  print("After plot 1, before plot 2")
  plot(2, main = "2")
  
  print("After plot 2, before plot 3 (Wrong!!??, appears BEFORE plot 2)")
  r <- testfun()
}
```
````

---

From the docs `?message`:

> message(..., domain = NULL, appendLF = TRUE)

so it seems you can only control the domain (which has to with translation)  and the line ending.

Comment: I guess this has to do with the way messages are returned from inside your function `testfun()` and later handeled inside the Rmd-chunk (togeher with the other `print()` and `plot()` calls... I guess there might be some kind of prioritization between `message()`, `print()`, `cat()`, `plot()` ...

Simply changing `message("in testfun")` into `print("in testfun")` provided a fast bugfix on my machine. Although this might not be suitable to tackle the real problem beneath.